# tinyMCE : how to enable image upload?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to add image upload to tinyMCE:

I use that:

```
 <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  tinymce.init(
  { selector:'textarea',
   plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste image"
  ],        
  automatic_uploads: true,
  images_upload_url: 'postAcceptor.php',
  images_upload_base_path: '/some/basepath',
  images_upload_credentials: true
   });     
   </script>
<textarea>Hello world</textarea>
```

This options only gives me the opportunity to put link to HTTP images, no features of uploading image

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `images_upload_xxxx` attributes will not auto-magically add a user interface/functionality to select images and insert into TinyMCE.  What those attributes do is tell TinyMCE what to do with Base64 images that end up in the editor when you do things like drag/drop images into the editor or use the Image Editor to modify an image in the editor.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

If you want a UI to select an image from your hard drive and insert it into the editor you have a couple of choices...

- Use a 3rd party plugin to do this (e.g. MoxieManager or others like it)
- Build your own code to handle this process

Of course the fastest answer is to use an existing 3rd party tool.  MoxieManager is commercial so there is a fee but you get support.  There are Open Source tools that do the same thing but the level of support for those will vary based on how active the projects are and how involved the community is for each project.